# Scan from Hbase for a date range and Insert the results into Hive

Tags: hive, hbase

Hbase table

Htable ( rowkey , cf:col1, cf:col2 cf:reverseTimestamp)

Can i get the records from Hbase tabe for a range of rows and 
inserting the results into Hive table?

Comment: im not sure hot to insert to hive but you defiantly can get a range of rows with hbase

Comment: Yes i know. But is there any way to insert those results into Hive. Thats the question.